# Hiding field if php post is empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form on page1.php, and when I click submit, it leads to page2.php which summarizes the selections. Below is the code on page2.php to get the selected information.

I am trying to hide certain rows if the php post is empty.

For example, if you see the code below, there is a Date, Time, From, To and Additional Stop. The first 4 lines are mandatory so it will appear always, however the last line, Additional stop is not mandatory, so when I don't fill up that field in the previous page1.php, it will appear on page2.php as "Additional Stop: (empty space).

Is there a way to have the word Additional Stop: only appear IF the php post add1 has been filled up, and if it has been left blank, it is hidden?

```
<dt>Date</dt>
<dd><?php echo isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : ''; ?></dd>
<dt>Time</dt>
<dd><?php echo isset($_POST['time']) ? $_POST['time'] : ''; ?></dd>
<dt>From</dt>
<dd><?php echo isset($_POST['pick']) ? $_POST['pick'] : ''; ?></dd>
<dt>To</dt>
<dd><?php echo isset($_POST['drop']) ? $_POST['drop'] : ''; ?></dd>
<dt>Additional Stop</dt>
<dd><?php echo isset($_POST['add1']) ? $_POST['add1'] : ''; ?></dd>
```

*I am new here, If I made a mistake with the tags let me know and I will change it. I tagged php because there is an above php code, html because its html and javascript because i think it may require javascript to be sorted. I say this because I was flamed previously for wrong tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go:**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['add1']) && !empty($_POST['add1'])){ ?>
    <dt>Additional Stop</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $_POST['add1']; ?></dd> // No need to have condition here then.
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

check if `$_POST['add1']` is set or not

try this

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['add1'])){ ?>
<dt>Additional Stop</dt>
<dd><?php echo isset($_POST['add1']) ? $_POST['add1'] : ''; ?></dd>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['add1']) && !empty($_POST['add1'])){
    echo '<dt>Additional Stop</dt>';
    echo '<dd>'.$_POST['add1'].'</dd>';
}
```